# Minimum distance using Frobenius Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $v_{0}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, prove that there is exactly one $h_0∈H$ having the property that $‖v_0-h_0‖≤‖v_0-h‖$ for all $h∈H$

we note that $H=span
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
$ is a subspace of $V=M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$ which is an inner product space where $\langle a,b\rangle$ is defined to be the Frobenius Inner Product

the best guess that I could take is that we can assume $h_0$ is a vector such that $‖v_0-h_0‖$ is a minimum. Then using Caucy-Schwarz Inequality, we let $f(x) = ‖v_0-xh_0‖$ and prove that it is a local minima.

Is this correct? If so, how can I go on.

Comment: This depends on what you are allowed to use. The space of $2 \times 2$ matrices with the Frobenius inner product is nothing else than $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the Euclidean inner product. So if you know this property for $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is a trivial consequence.

Comment: if forgot to add that $V=M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$. Though in that sense, I'm still clueless on how to approach the problem. I know that $h$ could be written as $h=\alpha_1\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}+\alpha_2\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}$ But that leads me to $||v_0-h_0||=\sqrt{2-2\alpha_1-2\alpha_2+2\alpha_1\alpha_2+3\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2}$ but there seems to be something that I am not getting.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in the previous comment, the difficulty of this problem depends on what you already know. For example, are you familiar with orthogonal projections in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept, that is $\langle\alpha-s\beta,\beta\rangle$ is a projection of $\alpha$ on $\beta$ and an orthogonal vector to $\beta$ is $\alpha-P_\beta\alpha$. How can this help me? Also, will the basis for $H^\perp$ be of any use.

Comment: Forget about all the variables for a moment. In the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, do you know that the orthogonal projection onto a subspace minimizes the distance ?

Comment: I did not. Could you please explain it further. Also, thanks for the time you're giving to answer my question.

Comment: I think you should look that up first then before you are dealing with more complicated matters. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections) is a good start.

Comment: @Klaus interesting observation. I'd like to see your approach.